# Where did the helpful comments to my question go?

Tags: support

My [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18509/need-easy-method-to-make-scipy-available-in-my-scripts) was marked as [duplicate] by several users, and there were some helpful comments, and I've edited it to help clarify what I need to understand beyond the answer to the related question. However now the original comments are not visible to me. Are they gone? Thanks!

Comment: They look pretty gone. Unfortunately AFAIK comments are one of the few things which can be permanently and irrevocably deleted on SE..

Comment: OK, thanks. They appear to have been automatically deleted when I edited the question, at least I didn't do any explicit deleting that I'm aware of.

Comment: That's odd.. AFAIK only the author and moderators can delete comments. Not sure what is going on here..

Comment: I have edited the question. When I log in, I can see my edits. When I am not logged in, it shows only the related question which is proposed to be the answer, and not my revised question with edits/clarification. I do not know what OTHER people see. Are my edits visible to others when they are logged in? If not, it seems like following the directions to edit the question does not actually do anything useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These were removed automatically by [Community](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) (a background process) since both links were the same as the post marked as a duplicate so nothing missed.